# In openerp, how can I override the base list price of a product?

Tags: module, overriding, product, odoo

I have code external to OpenERP that functions as an existing product pricing system. Each of our products have a base price that is determined in a somewhat complex way.

This external system manages and creates sales orders in OpenERP via the RPC api.

We would like to remove code from our external pricing system that calculates price information, /after/ it has already determined a base price. That is, in OpenERP terms, each product would have (say) ten different list prices.

From here, we would like to use OpenERP's pricelist system to preform further calculations on this base price.

Currently, I have code that asks OpenERP for a product price:

```
...
    date_order = time.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT) #Pricelists are seasonal
    price = self.pool.get('product.pricelist').price_get(cr, uid, [pricelist_id], product.id, qty, partner.id, {
        'uom': uom,
        'date': date_order,
    })[pricelist_id]

...
    price_taxes = tax_obj.compute_all(cr, uid, tax_objs, price, qty, billing_addr.id, product.id, partner.id)
```

This works correctly and gives me the price of a particular product.

The pricelist tree (since pricelists can be based on each other, etc) eventually calls `product_product.price_get(self, cr, uid, ids, ptype='list_price', context=None)` which reads the list_price via `self.browse( ... )[ptype]`.

I think that the simplest way to modify this is a per-request override on product.list_price. By this i mean creating an rpc method that sets a variable in the context, and modifying price_get to read the context var instead of the product object.

Another alternative is to use a thread-local, but this still is a modification of the price_get function.

I was thinking about overriding the column definition and adding a getter method, but i'm not sure if it would be used from a self.browse call.

What would you recommend? Override `price_get`, override the column `list_price`, or something else?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "return super(product_product, self).price_get(cr, uid, ids, ptype, context)" : You cannot use the price_get() from parent product_product because your class is inherited from osv.osv.
So How does that work?

Comment: I think you replied to the wrong area. If you meant for below, I didn't get that error, and don't know where that would have come from. I developed this on 6.0, and it works there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue like this:

```
class product_product(osv.osv):
    def _get_dyn_list_price(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        res = {}
        b = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        for obj in b:
            res[obj.id] = context.get('dyn_prices', {}).get(obj.id, None)
        return res

    _name = _inherit = 'product.product'
    _columns = {
        'dynamic_list_price': fields.function(_get_dyn_list_price, type='float', method=True, string='Dynamic List Price', store=False, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Sale Price'), help="Dynamic base price for product after applying door styles, etc.", readonly=True),
    }

    def price_get(self, cr, uid, ids, ptype='list_price', context=None):
        if ptype != 'list_price':
            return super(product_product, self).price_get(cr, uid, ids, ptype, context)
        ptype = 'dynamic_list_price' #Will cause price_margin / price_extra to not be respected
        res = super(product_product, self).price_get(cr, uid, ids, ptype, context)

        for k, v in res.iteritems():
            if v is None:
                if context.get('require_dyn_prices', False):
                    raise osv.except_osv('Error !', 'Dynamic prices required, but product ID not found in context.')
                res[k] = super(product_product, self).price_get(cr, uid, [k], ptype, context)[k]
        return res
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
    date_order = time.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT) #Pricelists are seasonal
    price = self.pool.get('product.pricelist').price_get(cr, uid, [pricelist_id], product.id, qty, partner.id, {
        'uom': uom,
        'date': date_order,
        'dyn_prices': {product.id: unit_price},
        'require_dyn_prices': True,
    })[pricelist_id]
```

Comment: congrats :)  However ur question was hard to understand. Maybe u can explain it in more detail so that we can all learn from it.

Comment: Essentially, I have product variants that do not direct affect OpenERP's stock-keeping system that do affect the price. The price is calculated externally, but I wanted to pass it through OpenERP's pricelist functionality. The code above does that with less hackery than I initially thought would be needed.